# Oscilloscope "isolated" inputs

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, instrumentation-amplifier, probe

As I don't want to see my oscilloscope go up in flames when I play with probing circuits, I was wondering the following:

First off, my goal is to measure different floating voltages aka the "GND" might not be the same.

- If I only work with low voltages (around 24 V max) and usually DC or PWM, is it possible to make a DIY differential probe using an op-amp (or 3) as a differential amplifier or use a instrumentation amplifier IC?
- If the former is true, is it safe to assume that when using more than one oscilloscope channel (with differential amplifier connected to them) will effectively isolate the different "GND" points and yield accurate measurements, even if in reality the inputs are floating? I know everything has a common GND via R6 (look at picture) so it wouldn't truly be isolated, but getting accurate readings and not burning anything is good enough for me.
- If none of the above is true ... what do I do?

Here's a picture of the circuit I'm talking about. I can either use the right part or the whole thing. However when playing around, the differential amplifier part actually gave me an accurate reading, while the whole circuit didn't work. I used LM324N and probed a floating battery voltage.

Any ideas and thoughts on the whole thing are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Most oscilloscopes can easily handle the voltages you are talking about but to be sure, check the manual for your specific scope.  It should detail what voltages it can withstand.  For larger voltages the usual method is to get a probe that has a divider network in it.

Comment: I've edited your question to replace "differentiator" with "differential amplifier". A differentiator is typically a single opamp circuit performing the opposite function of an integrator, and not the same thing as a differential or instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: ... and yes, what you're proposing to do is perfectly fine. In fact you can buy commercial differential probes for your 'scope which do pretty much the exact same thing as your proposed circuit here, with a pair of "floating" differential inputs on one side, a BNC on the other, and a battery-powered instrumentation amp circuit in the middle.

Comment: You do still need to be aware of the common-mode input range of your instrumentation amp though. As long as you respect that it should work fine. There are some work-arounds to extend the CM range - for example a differential voltage divider between the inputs and local ground, followed by some amplification in the in-amp.

Comment: Why doesn't the full circuit work though? I've tested it and only the one opamp differentiator works. If I use the LM324N as shown in my original picture, the circuit doesn't work. No clue why.